# How does the concept for external angle applies to this Polygon?

Tags: geometry

hello, hello.

I am reading the book "Geometry" by Tatiana Alekseyevskaya (Gelfand) and found myself having the question below.

An external angle is defined in Wikipedia [as an angle formed by one side of a simple polygon and a line extended from an adjacent side.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_and_external_angles)

How does that definition applies to the following polygon (delimited by the green line)?
[image]

If I extend one side of it, the angle will end inside the polygon.

I also have found similar questions have been [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298895/exterior-angle-definition-in-the-case-of-concave-polygons) over this forum, but I suppose mine is more related to the definition itself being applied, unless this polygon doesn't qualify as "simple" polygon as the Wikipedia definition states.

Thanks!

--
Caleb

Comment: Look on the Wikipedia page you linked to. There is a figure similar to yours with a "concave" angle like yours, and it is clearly marked on the figure how to interpret the external angle. Yes, the angle extends inside the polygon. The angle value is negative.

Comment: So the "external" angle is inside the polygon?! (No kidding question)

Comment: Yes! That's one reason why the measurement of the angle has to be a negative number. Negative $30$ degrees "outside" the polygon works out to $30$ degrees inside the polygon.

Comment: Thank you David K! I would never imagine that on my own, since the word "external" means thigs like the ones depicted over here: https://www.etymonline.com/word/external  Thank you again pal.